# How to get the z-index of a view/layout ? Or how to know if it is on front?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to get the z-index of a view/layout ? Or how to know if it is on front?
I need it specifically for a RelativeLayout

What I am looking for is something like view.getIndex() or view.isOnFront()

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
RelativeLayout re=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyRelative);
    int[] zIndexTab=new int[re.getChildCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < re.getChildCount(); i++) {
        zIndexTab[i]=re.getChildAt(i).getId(); // zIndexTab[0] will have the Id of the first child in this Layout etc..
        // So the first index corresponding to the first view.
        // The smaller View index will be under the biggest View Index
        // for example my first View is a button it's index is 0 , the second view is a spinner it's index is 1
        // so the spinner will be on the front of the button etc..
    }
```

Comment: What happens if two views that I need to access are part of different layouts??

Answer (score 0):

The views will be drawn in the order of appearance.
So the first is bottom z-index, the last top z-index

Comment: They're manipulated so the order changes. What I need is something like view.getIndex() or view.isOnFront()

Comment: @stefanbachert this should be a votable and acceptable answer. thanks.